# How to display disk usage by file type?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

Basically I'm wondering where all my disk space is being eaten up on my drive and I would like to be able to analyze by file type

For example, I'd like to use the Terminal to see how much space is being used by the `.psd` files on my drive.

Is there a way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -iname '*.psd' -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=-
```

- `find . -iname '*.psd'` finds all files that end with an extension of `psd`
- `-print0` prints the file names followed by a null character instead of a newline
- `| du -ch --files0-from=-` takes the file names from `find` and computes the disk usage. The options tell `du` to:

  - compute the disk usage of file names separated by a null character from stdin (`--files0-from=-`),
  - print sizes in a human readable format (`-h`), and
  - print a total in the end (`-c`).

Change `.psd` to whatever file type you want to find the disk usage for.

Comment: how to sort the output by size?

Comment: To sort it by size, I added (just after =-) a space and then | sort -h

Answer (score 6):

More generically, you could use a combination of `find` and `awk` to report disk usage grouping by any rule you choose. Here's a command that groups by file extensions (whatever appears after the final period):

```
# output pairs in the format: `filename size`.
# I used `nawk` because it's faster.
find -type f -printf '%f %s\n' | nawk '
  {
    split($1, a, ".");       # first token is filename
    ext = a[length(a)];      # only take the extension part of the filename
    size = $2;               # second token is file size
    total_size[ext] += size; # sum file sizes by extension
  }
  END {
    # print sums
    for (ext in total_size) {
      print ext, total_size[ext];
    }
  }'
```

Would produce something like

```
wav 78167606
psd 285955905
txt 13160
```

Comment: A sorted version of this that works for macOS: https://gist.github.com/dannyNK/41f08ee7717d1b545a63c80ad61708a2

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, you can. The syntax for searching files in terminal is:

```
Syntax   :   find foldername -iname '.filetype' -size size 

Example  :   find $HOME -iname '*.mp3' -size +1M
```

For your scenario it has to be like

```
find $HOME -iname '*.psd' -size +0M
```

For more information see official document [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal.).

Comment: Yes but this will only *print* the file names that are +0M, it won't actually tell me their size.

Comment: Yes, I saw your answer perfect!